# Why the cs50's checker doesn't work? -professor.py

Tags: python, cs50

I'm currently following the CS50 course: 'CS50's Introduction to Programming with Python.' In Problem Set 4, there is an exercise where I have to create a specific math mini-game.

When I attempt to run the CS50 checker, it gives me a few errors. Can someone help?

This is the code: (I know sys is not necessary)

```
import random
import sys

# generate 10 math problems
def main():
    n = get_level()
    for _ in range(10):
        x, y = generate_integer(n)
        for i in range(3):
            try:
                answ = int(input(f"{x} + {y} = "))
            except ValueError:
                continue
            else:
                if answ == x + y:
                    break
                else:
                    print("EEE")
                    if i == 2:
                        print(f"{x} + {y} = {x+y}")
                    continue
    sys.exit()
            
# ask user for a number between 1 and 3: n
def get_level():
    while True:
        try:
            n = int(input("Level: "))
            if 0 < n < 4:
                return n
            else:
                raise ValueError
        except ValueError:
            continue
            
# generate values
# digits of x and y are == n
def generate_integer(level):
    min_value = 10**(level-1)
    max_value = 10**level - 1
    x = random.randint(min_value, max_value)
    y = random.randint(min_value, max_value)
    return x, y
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

These are the errors:

```
:) professor.py exists
:) Little Professor rejects level of 0
:) Little Professor rejects level of 4
:) Little Professor rejects level of "one"
:) Little Professor accepts valid level
:( At Level 1, Little Professor generates addition problems using 0–9
    Did not find "6 + 6 =" in "Level: 7 + 7 =..."
:) At Level 2, Little Professor generates addition problems using 10–99
:) At Level 3, Little Professor generates addition problems using 100–999
:| Little Professor generates 10 problems before exiting
    can't check until a frown turns upside down
:| Little Professor displays number of problems correct
    can't check until a frown turns upside down
:| Little Professor displays EEE when answer is incorrect
    can't check until a frown turns upside down
:| Little Professor shows solution after 3 incorrect attempts
    can't check until a frown turns upside down
```

This is the exercise:

"One of David’s first toys as a child, funny enough, was [Little Professor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Professor), a “calculator” that would generate ten different math problems for David to solve. For instance, if the toy were to display `4 + 0 =` , David would (hopefully) answer with `4`. If the toy were to display `4 + 1 =` , David would (hopefully) answer with `5`. If David were to answer incorrectly, the toy would display `EEE`. And after three incorrect answers for the same problem, the toy would simply display the correct answer (e.g., `4 + 0 = 4` or `4 + 1 = 5`).

In a file called `professor.py`, implement a program that:

- Prompts the user for a level, n. If the user does not input `1`, `2`, or `3`, the program should prompt again.
- Randomly generates ten (10) math problems formatted as `X + Y =` , wherein each of `X` and `Y` is a non-negative integer with n digits. No need to support operations other than addition (`+`).
- Prompts the user to solve each of those problems. If an answer is not correct (or not even a number), the program should output `EEE` and prompt the user again, allowing the user up to three tries in total for that problem. If the user has still not answered correctly after three tries, the program should output the correct answer.
- The program should ultimately output the user’s score: the number of correct answers out of 10.

Structure your program as follows, wherein `get_level` prompts (and, if need be, re-prompts) the user for a level and returns `1`, `2`, or `3`, and `generate_integer` returns a randomly generated non-negative integer with `level` digits or raises a `ValueError` if `level` is not `1`, `2`, or `3`:

```
import random


def main():
    ...


def get_level():
    ...


def generate_integer(level):
    ...


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: What about the requirement `The program should ultimately output the user’s score: the number of correct answers out of 10.`? Also, not sure how to read the errors you are getting, is that literally the output?

Comment: *"If an answer is not correct (or not even a number), the program should output EEE and prompt the user again"* If the user inputs an answer that isn't a number, your program doesn't output "EEE".

Comment: Also, note that the failing test is described as "At Level 1, Little Professor generates addition problems using 0–9". When `level==1`, what are the maximum and minimum values that your `generate_integer()` can return?

Comment: The errors are the results of the CS50 checker. I added what I missed (the output "EEE" and the score at the end), but it still isn't being accepted.

Comment: When `level==1`, what are the maximum and minimum values that your `generate_integer()` can return?

Comment: When level is equal to 1, the minimum and maximum values are 0 and 9.

Comment: But `min_value = 10**(level-1)`. What is `10**0`?

Comment: Yeah, you're right; actually, they are 1 and 9.

Comment: Right, so that's probably why the test "At Level 1, Little Professor generates addition problems using 0–9" fails. (A bit weird that it mentions `6 + 6...` in the output though)

Comment: Just fixed it, and it was actually the problem. Thanks a lot.